# Angular Http Get with parameter

Tags: angularjs

I am calling a service using angular as follows:

```
return $http.get('api/properties', { params: { id: id } });
```

In this case the resulting url is:

```
api/properties?id=2
```

So I am getting an error because I would need:

```
api/properties/2
```

What would be the correct way have this url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds silly but concatenate the string will do

```
$http.get('api/properties/' + id);
```

Comment: yes, that is the obvious solution ... i just wasn't sure if that would be the correct option ... it seems to be. thanks